# Python Convert a part of a String into Float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a list containing 2 strings:

`List=["Hight = 7.2", "baselength = 8.32"]`

But I am having a problem trying to extract the numbers from the strings:

For example:

If `"Hight = 7.2"` then the result should be: `7.2`

or if the `"Hight= 7.3232"` then the result should be: `7.3232`

Comment: That is what regular expressions are made for: `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - convert this to float and you're fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) :

```
>>> out = []
>>> for s in l: 
        out.append( float(re.findall('\d+(?:\.\d+)?', s)[0]) ) 

>>> out
=> [7.2, 8.0]
```

Or, without `regex`, using `split`,

```
>>> out = []
>>> for s in l:
        num = s.replace(' ','').split('=')[1]    
        #note : removed whitespace so don't have to deal with cases like
        #        `n = 2` or `n=2`
        out.append(float(num)) 

>>> out
=> [7.2, 8.0]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = ["Hight = 7.2","baselength = 8"]
```

Comment: Fails on e.g. `100`

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
[(item.split('=')[0],float(item.split('=')[1]) ) for item in List]
```

Output :

```
[('Hight ', 7.2), ('baselength ', 8.32)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a label associated to a value is best managed with a dictionary, however if you must have each label=value pair as an entry in a list because perhaps you are reading it into Python from elsewhere, you could use the `re` module to extract the numeric value from each string in the list:

```
import re
list=["height = 7.2", "length = 8.32"]
for dim in list:
    print(float(re.search('\d+.\d+', dim).group()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could ***convert*** your list to a dictionary using a comprehension:

```
import re

List=["Height = 7.2", "baselength = 8.32"]

rx = re.compile(r'(?P<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?P<value>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')

Dict = {m.group('key'): float(m.group('value')) 
        for item in List
        for m in [rx.search(item)]}

print(Dict)
# {'Height': 7.2, 'baselength': 8.32}
```

Afterwards, you can access your values with e.g. `Dict["Height"]` (here: `7.2`).

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Use this method for any type of value

```
List=["Hight = 7.2", "baselength = 8.32"]
# showing example for one value , but you can loop the entire list 
a = List[0].split("= ")[1] #accessing first element and split with "= "
print a
'7.2'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I needed a simple solution (without imports) and here it is. This solution works great after I convert the result to float. Tnx again :)